# Migrating an HTTPS-website to another domain name on a single IP

Tags: redirect, https, 301-redirect

I am running a website using HTTPS protocol (nginx webserver). Now I would like to migrate it to a new domain name.

I did it multiple times while using HTTP. However with HTTPS it would be different, because a different certificate should be served for the new domain name.

What pitfalls to know about in advance and to avoid? What is the best way to go through migration as smoothly as possible?

Comment: If you can accept not supporting people running really old browsers with no SNI support then it is pretty easy.  Just setup your new site, get a cert for the new site make sure SNI is enabled and redirect the same was as you did for http.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect people to still request the page using the old domain (DOMAIN-A.COM) then you'll need to have that cert still alive and in effect so they don't get errors.   At that point you'll either need to redirect them or, my preference, display a notification to them that the server is being relocated to the new domain (DOMAIN-B.COM) and give them the opportunity to bookmark that new location.  Otherwise you'll never have a smooth transition from one to the other when DOMAIN-A.COM no is no longer available.  You'll still have some fall-out though.  Someone is bound to ask for DOMAIN-A when it's gone.  As for the cert, I don't see there would be much problem aside from maintaining two certs for a while.

Comment: In my practice old domains are maintained for a long time after transition, maybe even perpetually to keep effect from incoming links pointing to the old domain and not to let any user to experience any discomfort.

Comment: I agree with user...